# Java - Get multiple JSON values and turn into String

Tags: java, json

How would I get all the "name" values and turn them into a String?
So for example if I'd do the following:

```
System.out.println(value[1]);
```

It would print out `name1`.
Here is what I have so far:

JSON:

```
[
    {
        "name":"name1"
    },
    {
        "name":"name2",
        "changedToAt":1470659096000
    },
    {
        "name":"name3",
        "changedToAt":1473435817000
    }
]
```

Java code:

```
try {
    String UUID = p.getUniqueId().toString();
    String slimUUID = UUID.replace("-", "");
    InputStream in = new URL("https://api.mojang.com/user/profiles/" + slimUUID + "/names").openStream();

    String json = IOUtils.toString(in);
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);

    try {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject jsonparse = (JSONObject) parser.parse(json);
        //get "name" values and turn into String
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: what JSON library do you use?

Comment: json-simple. I'm also open to use gson.

Comment: please check my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate over array and accumulate all `name` values into array of Strings.

So below is working source code:

```
JsonArray jsonObject = new JsonParser()
        .parse(json)
        .getAsJsonArray();

List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
for (JsonElement jsonElement : jsonObject) {
    names.add(jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("name").getAsString());
}

//now you can use as you wish, by index
System.out.println(names.get(1));//returns "name2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the URL from your comment and Java 8 Stream API I've built this main method:

```
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws ParseException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
    final String url = "https://api.mojang.com/user/profiles/c8570e47605948d3a3cbe3ec3a681cc0/names";
    final InputStream in = new URL(url).openStream();
    final String json = IOUtils.toString(in);
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);
    final JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    final JSONArray jsonparse = (JSONArray) parser.parse(json);
    System.out.println(jsonparse);
    System.out.println();
    final List<String> names = (ArrayList<String>) jsonparse.stream().map((obj) -> {
        final JSONObject object = (JSONObject) obj;
        return (String) object.getOrDefault("name", "");
    }).peek(System.out::println).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: This works, but I like Yaroslav's answer better, thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

Try My library: [abacus-common](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-common). All the above can be replaced with:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> resp = HttpClient.of("https://api.mojang.com/user/profiles/" + slimUUID + "/names").get(List.class);
List<String> names = resp.stream().map(m -> (String) (m.get("name"))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

By the way, if slimUUID is equal to: `UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll("-", "")`. It's be simplified:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> resp = HttpClient.of("https://api.mojang.com/user/profiles/" + N.guid()+ "/names").get(List.class);
List<String> names = resp.stream().map(m -> (String) (m.get("name"))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```